# How to speed up single query with large dataset sql server and php

Tags: sql-server

I would like to know what can I do to speed up a simple query, but returns a large dataset like 2 millions rows. It's taking 30 seconds roughly to run this single select query and I need to process on the results with another table that's on a different server. I tried doing a join between the two servers, but that's also really slow about 22 seconds for top 5 rows.

Here's my single query

```
SELECT
 LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), r.id), 2)) AS id,
 r.id AS respondentid,
 'new' AS qtype,
 r.email,
 r.language,
'Y' AS is_online,
 r.createdDate AS time,
  r.createdDate AS date_sent,
   r.state AS state,
   r.sourceID AS sourceid
  FROM [Example_Server].dbo.[Example_Table] AS r
```

Here's the query that tries to do a left join on two tables on two different servers.

```
SELECT
LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), r.id), 2)) AS id,
r.id AS respondentid,
'new' AS qtype,
r.email,
r.language,
'Y' AS is_online,
r.createdDate AS time,
r.createdDate AS date_sent,
r.state AS state,
r.sourceID AS sourceid,
req.id
FROM [Example_Server1].[Example_Database1].[dbo].Example_Table1 AS r
LEFT JOIN [Example_Server2].[Example_Database2].[dbo].Example_Table2 req ON 
LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), r.id), 2)) = req.id 
WHERE req.id is null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try adding a WHERE clause? Is the time noted how long it takes to run on the actual SQL server?

Comment: Note that when you use a function in your join like this is has to perform that function on every single row in the remote database. This means that any indexes have been rendered useless.

Comment: Yes this is the time on the actual Sql Server. In the second query I added a Where clause to basically get all rows that's not in the first table. I don't know if it's because I'm comparing id on two different servers but it slows down tremendously. Also I'm using PDO to execute the query is there a certain mode that I need to run this query in. I've tried most of them but see no notable difference.

Comment: I have to use the functions because the id in table1 is converted to the id in table2, so in order for me to compare I have to convert it.

Comment: I would imagine the biggest issue is that `req.id` and `r.id` are not the same data type so the double `CONVERT` and `LOWER` are significat slowdowns. In Oracle, you can index an expression; does SQL Server support something similar? Quite honestly, this is purely a SQL issue. I think you would have better luck asking this on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm more of a MySql guy so sql server is not my go to, but my job uses it. So I'm stuck with it at the moment. I'm not aware of indexing an expression.

Comment: @EricEvans In Oracle you can create an index on the `Example_Table1` like `LOWER(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CONVERT(VARBINARY(32), id), 2))` so when you use it in a SQL statement such as yours then it knows to use the index. I recommend finding out if SQL Server has something similar. Professional advice: nobody cares if you are a MySQL guy, I'm sure that a SQL Server guy would love to be in your shoes so be the best that you can be and keep digging. Just because StackOverflow makes it easy to throw your hands up and give up it does not mean that you should do that.

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus for the advice. Wasn't giving up I actually started looking when you mentioned it. I'm not new to development just wasn't aware of the technology. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Np and good luck. Another idea is to convert data type of one of those id columns to match the other table but I am sure that would cause other headaches. You could also opt to create an additional `id2` column which uses the correct data type so that your SQL does not have to jump through `CONVERT()` hoops.

Comment: You cannot index an expression in sql server. You could create a computed and persisted column that you could index. Of course this means you have two copies of the data in one of your tables but would minimize the pain for cross database queries like this. Another option would be to create an indexed view.

Comment: Thanks MonkeyZeus and I'll check that out and see what I could up with. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: @SeanLange or select the data from the linked servers into a temp table and index appropriately. Amazing how many people dont realise you cannot index a function.